# Python - importing class from another file and getting error

Tags: python, selenium

I'm running selenium using python. I'm creating automation for web testing. I'm trying to separate some classes and save it as "modules" which I want to import to main. When I'm trying to start it I'm getting error like below. It won't load driver from main. Why is it like that?
Main code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from Modules.login import login

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://172.16.115.124:8080/econsole")
login()
time.sleep(10)
```

"Module":

```
def login():
username = "admin"
password = "admin"
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginModel"]/div/div/div[3]/input[1]').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginModel"]/div/div/div[3]/input[2]').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginModel"]/div/div/div[5]/a/div/div').click()
```

Error:

[image: ERROR]

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to `from Module import driver` on your main script. That said, you'll probably want to do something better like moving your `find_element` calls to the main script, or giving `login()` a structure like this:

```
def login(driver):
    username = "admin"
    password = "admin"
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginModel"]/div/div/div[3]/input[1]').send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginModel"]/div/div/div[3]/input[2]').send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginModel"]/div/div/div[5]/a/div/div').click()
```

and, if you want to keep this function it its own module, then don't forget to import `By` and other stuff in `Module` as well.

Answer (score 0):

`driver` is not defined in `login()` nor is it a global in that module. It's defined only in your main module. An easy solution is to pass that variable in.

```
def login(driver):
    username = "admin"
    password = "admin"
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginModel"]/div/div/div[3]/input[1]').send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginModel"]/div/div/div[3]/input[2]').send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginModel"]/div/div/div[5]/a/div/div
```

Then when you call it, pass `driver`:

```
login(driver)
```

Comment: That did the job for me, thanks